# Passing control to another controller

Tags: redirection

In a module I use forms. On special occasions I have to start another form in another module.
In this case I would like to do the following:
1 pass the control from the form to the Controller(1) of the module 
2 this Controller(1) should then pass the control to the Controller(2) of the other module
3 this Controller(2) should start the desired form

Step 1 and 3 I can perform

Step 2 is still a problem because I read that a controller always must render output.
I do not want to create a new instance of Controller 2 in Controller 1.

Found out that you can return a redirect to another controller. The parameter handling is not yet clear to me, I cannot find a good tutorial about the usage ofRedirect and passing parameters with it.

Comment: Are you looking for multistep form or something similar? If yes, refer [this link](https://www.drupal.org/node/717750).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My aim is the implementation of a [Mediator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern). Best practice to do this is using the Event Dispatcher Mechanism.
This is explained [here](https://drupalize.me/blog/201502/responding-events-drupal-8).

A good example of implementing the mechanism, even create your own event type (above the existing types of Drupal) is described [here](http://valuebound.com/resources/blog/how-to-define-an-event-dispatcher-and-subscriber-drupal-8)